# Colormap it's not composed of correct color

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I need to make a colormap with 256 colors from black to red to white and display the red channel in Python but it looks like the only black to red its display and I don't understand why... Also the red channel only it's not displayed. Here it's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# How to create an array filled with zeros
img = np.zeros([256,256])
colormap = np.zeros([256,3])

#image:
for i in range(256):
    img[:,i] = i #on all columns I have the same value
    
#color map:
for i in range(128):
    colormap[i,0] = i/127 
    colormap[i+128,0] = 1 #from line 128 incolo I have 1 on first position because I've already reached red
    colormap[i+128,2] = (i+1)/128
    
#display the thing:
colormap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colormap)
plt.figure(), plt.imshow(img, cmap = colormap)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this line in your code :

```
colormap[i+128,1] = (i+1)/128
```

You couldn't have white because the green value was always equal to 0.

To go from red to white, you should have the following values of RGB :

```
[1,0,0]
...
[1,0.5,0.5]
...
[1,1,1]
```